# Direction of gradient and contour lines using unit vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

A valley is described by $h(r)=e^{xy}$ w/ $r=(x,y)^T$.
With the gradient $\nabla h_r=(\partial_xh,\partial_yh)^T=e^{xy}*(y,x)^T$ and the total differential $dh_r(n)=\partial_xh*n_x+\partial_yh*n_y=e^{xy}*(xn_x+yn_y)$

I now need to find the direction of the gradient vector and the contour lines of said gradient.

I thought of using a parallel unit vector to the gradient for it's direction $$n_{||}=\frac{\nabla h_r}{||\nabla h_r||}$$

And then using a vector ($n_{\bot}$) perpendicular to that, to get the direction of the contour lines.

The problem I am facing is that I just can't seem to be able to calculate them explicitly.

Comment: The direction of the gradient is the unit vector associated with the gradient so all you need to do is divide the gradient by it's length. Also what do you mean contour lines of the gradient, do you mean what direction the contour lines increase/decrease? Or the vector parallel to them?

Comment: Right, but I am stuck trying to do exactly that but can't seem to get anywhere. I am sorry, I made a mistake there, what I meant were the contour lines of the valley, I need to find the vector parallel to them.

Comment: The length In your case it's $\sqrt{e^{2xy}(x^2+y^2)}$